# load one item per page [ Pagination ]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, pagination

I have a viewpage like below

[image]

this is the controller method for above view

```
public ActionResult Add_Product()
{       
    var model = new AddNewProduct
    {
        ListProductFields = db.AB_ProductTypeCategoryField.ToList()
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

this is model class for above view

```
public class AddNewProduct
{
    public string Product_ID { get; set; }
    public string ProductTypeID { get; set; }
    public string ProductCategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Subsidary_ID { get; set; }

    public IList<AB_ProductTypeCategoryField> ListProductFields { get; set; }
}
public partial class AB_ProductTypeCategoryField
{
    public string Field_Value_EN { get; set; }
    public string Field_Value_AR { get; set; }
}
```

this is viewpage

```
@model albaraka.Models.AddNewProduct

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{        

        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListProductFields.Count; i++)
        { 
          @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ListProductFields[i].Field_Value_EN, new { @class = "form-control summernote", @row = 5 })

          @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ListProductFields[i].Field_Value_AR, new { @class = "form-control summernote", @row = 5 })
        }

}
```

Now I want to add pagination for above view page and limit one `ListProductFields` per one page , for that I following [this Tutorial](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/10/30/ASPNET-MVC-Pagination-Example-with-Logic-like-Google.aspx)

So I change my code to like this

```
    public ActionResult Add_Product(int? page)
    {

        var dummyItems = db.AB_ProductTypeCategoryField.Select(x => "Item " + x);
        var pager = new PaginationModel.Pager(dummyItems.Count(), page);


        var model = new AddNewProduct
        {
            Items = dummyItems.Skip((pager.CurrentPage - 1) * pager.PageSize).Take(pager.PageSize).ToList(),
            Pager = pager
        };

        return View(model);

    }
```

But then I'm getting following Run-time Error

> Values of type 'AB_ProductTypeCategoryField' can not be converted to string.

Comment: After changing the code, what changes have you incorporated in the View?

Comment: just added the code under ` <!-- pager -->` [in this](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/10/30/ASPNET-MVC-Pagination-Example-with-Logic-like-Google.aspx) example view section

Comment: `AB_ProductTypeCategoryField` is an object; in select `db.AB_ProductTypeCategoryField.Select(x => "Item " + x);` you are selected concatenating with string, that's why the error is throw. Either change it to `db.AB_ProductTypeCategoryField.Select(x => "Item " + x.ToString());`  after overriding the ToString method of class or a property has to be selected then change it as `db.AB_ProductTypeCategoryField.Select(x => "Item " + x.Field_Value_EN);`

Comment: @user1672994 can you clearly explain this as an answer ?

Comment: @user1672994 as you said I changed `var dummyItems = db.AB_ProductTypeCategoryField.Select(x => "Item " + x.ToString());` then I'm getting following error `Values of type 'AB_ProductTypeCategoryField' can not be converted to string.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with following code , so you cannot use `Skip` method alone. so have use `OrderBy` before it

```
var dummyItems = db.AB_ProductTypeCategoryField;
            var pager = new PaginationModel.Pager(dummyItems.Count(), page);

            var model = new AddNewProduct
            {
                ListProductFields = dummyItems.OrderBy(i => i.SomeProperty).Skip((pager.CurrentPage - 1) * pager.PageSize).Take(pager.PageSize).ToList(),
                Pager = pager
            };

            return View(model);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue of your observation is below line

```
var dummyItems = db.AB_ProductTypeCategoryField.Select(x => "Item " + x);
```

Since you are trying to select object with string concatenate operation ("Item " + x) that's why exception is thrown as `AB_ProductTypeCategoryField` is an object. I don't think you require `"Item " + x` at all.

You can change `AddNewProdcut` action implementation as

```
public ActionResult Add_Product(int? page)
    {
        var pager = new PaginationModel.Pager(dummyItems.Count(), page);

        var model = new AddNewProduct
        {
            ListProductFields = db.AB_ProductTypeCategoryField.Skip((pager.CurrentPage - 1) * pager.PageSize).Take(pager.PageSize).ToList(),
            Pager = pager
        };

        return View(model);

    }
```

Comment: getting this error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<project_name.Models.AB_ProductTypeCategoryField>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: Can you post the correct definition of `AddNewProduct` class?

Comment: How Items property is defined in `AddNewProduct` class?

Comment: here the relevant model classes https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/xK4Ay

Comment: Am I missing something here

Comment: I believe you require two text areas at page --- 1 for `Field_Value_EN` and 1 for `Field_Value_AR`. If that is true then why did you declared Items as `IEnumerable<string>`. It should be `List<AB_ProductTypeCategoryField>`. That being said why do you require Items you can use the `ListProductFields` directly (through fetching required records from DB based on pagination)

Comment: So I changed code as `ListProductFields = dummyItems.Skip((pager.CurrentPage - 1) * pager.PageSize).Take(pager.PageSize).ToList(),` but then I'm gettting this compile time error `The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.`

Comment: Can you try with `db.AB_ProductTypeCategoryField.Skip((pager.CurrentPage - 1) * pager.PageSize).Take(pager.PageSize).ToList()`